# Is it possible to define priorities for Celery workers consuming from the same queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have two machines on my network running Celery workers that process tasks from a common queue (the messaging back-end is RabbitMQ).

One machine is much more powerful and processes the tasks faster (which is important). If there is only one task in the queue, I always want it to run on this machine. If the queue is full, I want the less powerful machine to start accepting tasks as well.

**Is there a recommended, elegant way to do this?** Or do I have to set up two queues ("fast" and "slow") and implement some kind of router that sends tasks to the "slow" queue only when the "fast" queue is full?